# Uncaught TypeError: <nombre_función> is not a function

Tags: javascript

```js
    const tipoP = [
      { pago: "Tarjeta" },
      { pago: "Transferencia bancaria" },
      { pago: "Criptomonedas" },
      { pago: "Teléfono móvil" },
    ];
    const tipoH = [
      { habitacion: "Sencilla", precio: 31 },
      { habitacion: "Doble", precio: 62 },
      { habitacion: "Triple", precio: 93 },
      { habitacion: "Quat", precio: 120 },
    ];
    
    class Reserva{
      constructor(dni, nombre, apellido, tipoP,numero, tipoH, precio){
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.tipoP = tipoP;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.tipoH = tipoH;
        this.precio = precio;
        
      }
    }
    class Usuario extends Reserva{
      constructor(dni, nombre, apellido, tipoP,pagado) {
        super(dni, nombre, apellido, tipoP);
        this.pagado = pagado;
      }
      informacionUsu = function () {
        if (this.pagado === false) {
          return `El cliente con DNI: ${this.dni}, ${this.apellido}, ${this.nombre}, aun tiene que pagar`;
        } else {
          return `El cliente con DNI: ${this.dni}, ${this.apellido}, ${this.nombre}, ha pagado mediante ${this.tipoP}`;
        }
    
      };
    
    }
    let importe;
    class Habitacion extends Reserva{
      constructor(numero, tipoH,dias, precio) {
        super(numero, tipoH, precio);
        this.dias = dias;
        importe = dias * precio;
      }
      informacionHab = function () {
        return `ha reservado la habitacion ${this.numero} ${this.tipoH}, durante ${this.dias} dias a un precio de ${importe}€`;
      };
    }
    const reserva1 = new Reserva("55447701F", "Pepe", "Gomez",tipoP[1].pago,true,14,tipoH[1].habitacion,10,tipoH[1].precio);
    console.log(reserva1.informacionUsu());
    console.log(reserva1.informacionHab());
```

Al ejecutar el código anterior tengo el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: reserva1.informacionUsu is not a function

Por mas que intento encontrar el error no lo veo, seguro que es una tontería, pero estoy aprendiendo, perdón por las meteduras de pata
Gracias y espero respuesta...

Comment: Bueno, por lo que leo en tu código, `reserva1` es del tipo `Reserva`, y la clase `Reserva` no tiene declarado ningún método, por ello el error de que `reserva1.informacionUsu ` no es una función. ¿Qué esperas exactamente? No puedes crear un objeto `Reserva` y pretender que tenga métodos de otras clases cómo `Habitacion` o `Usuario`.

Comment: valeeee, jajajajaja los métodos tienen que estar en el padre, thnks, boss!!

Comment: De hecho la relaciones de herencia no están correctas. Un `Usuario` no es una `Reserva` y una `Habitación` no es una `Reserva`. Las relaciones son más bien de composición. Una reserva `tiene un` usuario y `tiene una` habitación. Checa [acá](https://gist.github.com/JaimeMenendez/b571d73c15f268dcdf8ece57309f42c8) una posible solución con composición que tiene mucho más sentido con tu código.

Comment: Jaime Menéndez, muchas gracias por contestar, entiendo mas o menos todo menos, los binds, exactamente, ¿para que se usan?

Comment: Jaime Menéndez
Esres un crack, muchas gracias, ojalá pronto pueda ayudar como me has ayudado tu a mi, un saludo muy cordial desde España!

Comment: Lo harás, solo sigue practicando y no pares. Considera, o bien responderte tú mismo, o eliminar la pregunta para que no quede abierta. Saludos!

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ¿Porqué dices que con las nuevas versiones de JS el `bind` ya no es necesario? ¿De dónde sacas eso?

Comment: @MauricioContreras si lees mi comentario dice `al parecer` y es que estaba convencido de que si no hacías un `bind` al objeto actual los métodos no tenían acceso a las propiedades de la clase, si no que `this` se refería al contexto global. Normalmente no trabajo con clases en javascript, pero recuerdo eso era siempre necesario en `react` cuando se trabajaba con clases, hacer un `bind` de los métodos del objeto en el constructor. Por lo visto, siempre estuve equivocado.

Comment: Acabo de verificar que el `bind` solo es necesario cuando se pasa un método como `callback`, ya que en este caso, el contexto del método se pierde, por eso acá si es necesario el `bind`. Gracias por el comentario @MauricioContreras , me ayudó a refrescar algunos conceptos.

Answer (score 1):

Una clase puede contener metodos staticos ; getter y setter;   metodo constructor para crear e inicializar un objeto creado a partir de una clase.Si no se especifica un método constructor, se utiliza un constructor predeterminado y tambien podemos definir a otros metodos pero definirlos como metodos de expresion  dentro de la clase puede dar errores segun el interprete

```js
const tipoP = [
    { pago: "Tarjeta" },
    { pago: "Transferencia bancaria" },
    { pago: "Criptomonedas" },
    { pago: "Teléfono móvil" },
];
const tipoH = [
    { habitacion: "Sencilla", precio: 31 },
    { habitacion: "Doble", precio: 62 },
    { habitacion: "Triple", precio: 93 },
    { habitacion: "Quat", precio: 120 },
];

class Reserva {
    constructor(habitacion, usuario, dias, tipoPago, pagado) {
        this.habitacion = habitacion;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.dias = dias;
        this.tipoPago = tipoPago;
        this.pagado = pagado;
        this.importe = dias * habitacion.precio;
    }

    informacionUsu () {
        if (this.pagado === false) {
            return `El cliente con DNI: ${this.usuario.dni}, ${this.usuario.apellido}, ${this.usuario.nombre}, aun tiene que pagar`;
        } else {
            return `El cliente con DNI: ${this.usuario.dni}, ${this.usuario.apellido}, ${this.usuario.nombre}, ha pagado mediante ${this.tipoPago}`;
        }
    };

    informacionHab  () {
        return `ha reservado la habitacion ${this.habitacion.numero} ${this.habitacion.tipoH}, durante ${this.dias} dias a un precio de ${this.importe}€`;
    };
}

class Usuario {
    constructor(dni, nombre, apellido) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
}
class Habitacion {
    constructor(numero, tipoH, precio) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.tipoH = tipoH;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}

const usuario = new Usuario("55447701F", "Pepe", "Gomez");
const habitacion = new Habitacion(1, tipoH[1].habitacion, tipoH[1].precio);
const reserva = new Reserva(habitacion, usuario, 14, tipoP[1].pago, true);
console.log(reserva.informacionUsu());
console.log(reserva.informacionHab());
```

Comment: Disculpa ser tan exigente, pero afirmas cosas que no aplican a Javascript. Una Clase no debe tener un método constructor obligatoriamente, por lo tanto tu afirmación: *"debe contener su metodo constructor"* no es correcta, yo la cambiaría por *puede contener un método constructor*. Por otro lado, no existen *compiladores* en Javascript, ya que no es un lenguaje compilado, al contrario, es un lenguaje interpretado. Tal vez a lo que te refieres es que hay diferentes intérpretes para el lenguaje, por ejemplo el motor (intérprete) de Chrome es distinto al motor de Mozilla. Saludos

Comment: es una discucion el tema de compilador igual lo modifique ya que  se lo considera Lenguaje Interpretado y  precisa un interprete en runtime Hay otros que lo consideran de otra forma Kyle Simpson en You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures  .Hoy se usan motores hibridos como V8 y WebKit los cuales compilan o interpretan segun la situacion

Answer (score 0):

Jaime Menéndez, GRACIAS CRACK!

```
const tipoP = [
    { pago: "Tarjeta" },
    { pago: "Transferencia bancaria" },
    { pago: "Criptomonedas" },
    { pago: "Teléfono móvil" },
];
const tipoH = [
    { habitacion: "Sencilla", precio: 31 },
    { habitacion: "Doble", precio: 62 },
    { habitacion: "Triple", precio: 93 },
    { habitacion: "Quat", precio: 120 },
];

class Reserva {
    constructor(habitacion, usuario, dias, tipoPago, pagado) {
        this.habitacion = habitacion;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.dias = dias;
        this.tipoPago = tipoPago;
        this.pagado = pagado;
        this.importe = dias * habitacion.precio;
    }

    informacionUsu = function () {
        if (this.pagado === false) {
            return `El cliente con DNI: ${this.usuario.dni}, ${this.usuario.apellido}, ${this.usuario.nombre}, aun tiene que pagar`;
        } else {
            return `El cliente con DNI: ${this.usuario.dni}, ${this.usuario.apellido}, ${this.usuario.nombre}, ha pagado mediante ${this.tipoPago}`;
        }
    };

    informacionHab = function () {
        return `ha reservado la habitacion ${this.habitacion.numero} ${this.habitacion.tipoH}, durante ${this.dias} dias a un precio de ${this.importe}€`;
    };
}

class Usuario {
    constructor(dni, nombre, apellido) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
}
class Habitacion {
    constructor(numero, tipoH, precio) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.tipoH = tipoH;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}

const usuario = new Usuario("55447701F", "Pepe", "Gomez");
const habitacion = new Habitacion(1, tipoH[1].habitacion, tipoH[1].precio);
const reserva = new Reserva(habitacion, usuario, 14, tipoP[1].pago, true);
console.log(reserva.informacionUsu());
console.log(reserva.informacionHab());
```

Comment: Una respuesta que no explica cómo se soluciona el problema y que sólo contiene código no aporta valor. Considera [edit] tu respuesta y describir cómo se soluciona el problema planteado. Eso no sólo te ayudará a ti, reforzando lo aprendido, sino que ayudará a otros que tengan un problema similar. Saludos

Comment: Discúlpeme, pero a mi me ha quedado claro, no había hecho las herencias correctamente, un saludo

Comment: Es que puede que te haya quedado claro, pero: recuerda que la idea de [es.so] es ayudar a todos quienes tienen un problema similar a la del autor de la pregunta, por lo tanto, la respuesta debe estar redactada como para que otros usuarios de la comunidad también lo comprendan (tal como lo mencionó @MauricioContreras). Lee [answer].